# Power series where its radius of convergence is infinity

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose that a power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ converges for $x$ in an interval $(-c,c)$ to a function $f$. Then, $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $(-c,c)$.

**Question**: Is true for the case $c= \infty$? If yes, could you please explain why this is the case?

Here is $c$ the radius of convergence, where I always have understood to be non-negative, so I do not know if $\infty$ is included.

Comment: It converges on $(-c,c)$ for all $c >0$ so it is smooth on $(-c,c)$ for all $c >0$

Comment: yes it's trivially true for $c=\infty$ since differentiability is a local property.

Comment: @peek-a-boo What do you mean by "local property"?

Comment: @reuns So, since it is smooth on $(-c,c)$ for all $c>0$, can you conclude that it is smooth on $\mathbb{R}$? Is this because that $c>0$ can be chosen arbitrarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiability being a local property means that differentiability depends only on the values of $f$ in a neighborhood of the point in question. To be more explicit and direct, you want to show $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}$. So, take a point $p\in\Bbb{R}$ and let $c_p=|p|+1$. Then, $c_p>0$, and clearly, $p\in (-c_p,c_p)$. Now, by hypothesis, you know $f$ is differentiable on this interval $(-c_p,c_p)$. Hence in particular, $f$ is differentiable at the point $p$.

Finally, since $p\in\Bbb{R}$ was taken arbitrarily, it follows $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)$, i.e the statement holds with $c=\infty$.

---

Note: I'm assuming you've already shown that a power series is (infinitely) differentiable inside the radius of convergence.

Comment: May I suggest to drop the superfluous $2$ and define $c_p =|p|+1$? it's more didactic.

Comment: @jjagmath thank you for the suggestion. (Looks like my subconscious was being extra safe thinking that "because $c$ had to cover both the positive and negative side, we multiply by 2", which is of course completely unnecessary as you point out). Also for OP: the choice of $c_p$ doesn't really matter, $|p|+1$ or $2|p|+1$ or $|p|+0.00001$ or whatever. All we care is that for every $p\in \Bbb{R}$, there is some $c_p>0$ such that $p\in (-c_p,c_p)$.